# How do I multiply two Gaussian distributions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to multiply two Gaussian distributions to obtain posterior for GMM data.  In order to do that, I am trying to use `.prob()` function from `tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag`, but every time I am getting the same error, even if I am providing the argument with `float64`.

I am using TensorFlow 1.8 version.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None,2], name="input")
likelihood = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc = [0., 0., 0.], scale_diag= [1., 1., 1.])

y_LL = likelihood.prob(x).eval()
```

> TypeError: Input had dtype `<dtype: 'float32'>` but expected `<dtype: 'float64'>.`

I am confused whether I am doing it the wrong way, or what? Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide us with [_minimal, complete, and verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It seems that you do not feed anything into your placeholder when `eval` is called. Could you show us more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

For this example, you are using x as a tf.float64. Unless you explicitly specify, tensorflow will auto-convert list inputs to tf.float32. You want to do something like (not executable code, but demonstrating you need to signal float64):

```
import numpy as np
likelihood = tf.contrib.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc=np.float64([0., 0., 0.]), scale_diag=np.float64([1., 1., 1.]))
y_LL = likelihood.prob(x).eval()
```